# Channel is unrecoverably broken android

Tags: android

I am testing my app on both physical device (android 4.0.4) and BlueStacks emulator. My app sometimes crashes on the physical device without showing any error or logcat. When I selected "No Filter" in logcat, I got he the following error. Help me to track down the issue, please.

```
08-04 20:38:57.606 238-273/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '418c06b8 com.fake.fake/com.fake.fake.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: In my case, i got this error when trying to clear the app from task manager and app is forcefully killing itself, PNS is not working there after